# How to use d3 word cloud in Drupal?

Tags: 7, blocks, charts

I am using [D3 word Cloud](https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud) locally on my computer. It works fine. It gets the data from the database and displays it as word cloud on webpage. I want to place the output from it in Drupal website. How do I place it as a block?

**EDIT:** I have 2 JavaScript file, a JSON file and a HTML file. All these files I want to include. I just realised that the HTML file has this code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="../lib/d3/d3.js"></script>
<script src="../d3.layout.cloud.js"></script>
<script>
  var fill = d3.scale.category20();

  d3.layout.cloud().size([800, 300])
      .words(["This", "is", "some", "random", "text"].map(function(d) {
        return {text: d, size: 10 + Math.random() * 90};
      }))
      .padding(5)
      .rotate(function() { return ~~(Math.random() * 2) * 90; })
      .font("Impact")
      .fontSize(function(d) { return d.size; })
      .on("end", draw)
      .start()
      ;

  function draw(words) {
    d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", 800)
        .attr("height", 300)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(150,150)")
      .selectAll("text")
        .data(words)
      .enter().append("text")
        .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.size + "px"; })
        .style("font-family", "Impact")
        .style("fill", function(d, i) { return fill(i); })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
        })
        .text(function(d) { return d.text; })
        .on("click", function(d) {
          var string_url = "http://etraining-dev/search/node/" + d.text;
          window.location = string_url;

  });;
  }
</script>
```

which is just script. I am not sure how to include these files and make it work. Can anyone help?

Thanks.

#### Background

[D3.js](http://d3js.org/) is a JavaScript library for manipulating documents based on data. I will need to add the d3 javascript library to the page, as well as the [D3 word Cloud](https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud) script. I then need some way of inserting the HTML5 canvas element in my content so that it can be manipulated by d3.

Comment: What's d3? How do you "have it"? What do you mean by "use it", exactly?

Comment: I imagine youll need to ask the 'D3' people how to embed their service into a web page. Then just add that code to the block. We can't help with the 'D3' software here I'm afraid, this is a site for questions about Drupal.

Comment: When you will have D3 up and running on your web server, and instruction @Clive mentioned ready at hand, feel welcome to edit this question and ask us how to apply it to Drupal :) I'll be glad to cast reopen vote then.

Comment: Hi Molot, I have  the code, there are two js files, one JSON file and a html file.

Comment: Can you tell me how do I add them together in Drupal?

Comment: No, I cannot. You haven't edited your question with information about how would you include it in pure html, so it's still not really a Drupal issue.

Comment: I believe I can help. I have reworded the question with background.

Comment: Thanks for editing the question. I was trying to create a custom module. I have never created any module yet. At the moment, I have added .info file and module file with a block in it. I assume, I have to insert html code inside block and include JS and JSON files.

Comment: In your module you could just drupal_add_js the d3 library and the d3 word cloud js within hook_block_view. Another way to start would be to install the d3 module. If this question is taken off hold I could provide more help

Comment: A really useful way to start with module creation is to take a look at the examples, in this case block_example: https://drupal.org/project/examples

Comment: Do you mean this? function manual_search_block_view()
{
drupal_add_js("path/to/JS1");
drupal_add_js("path/to/JS2");
}

How would I add the JSON file and HTML file having mostly script? Thanks

Comment: download the examples and copy the block_example folder into your modules directory. It will provide you with several clear examples of how to generate a block in drupal, as does this q http://goo.gl/Lhn3gW

Comment: Bala, Mołot, Clive - would any of you consider re-opening this question?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have downloaded them and going through it.

Comment: Hi I think understood some part of it. I have included js files in it. How do I include JSON file? and the content of HTML file? Should I copy it over to js file and include the file as it is only script in the file?

Comment: @autopoietic sure, done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Option 1 - simple

#### Generate a block using a custom module

Making a simple block module with drupal is really easy. The [examples](https://drupal.org/project/examples) project includes a block_example, this is a good starting point. The following is roughly what your module (d3wordcloud.module) should look like:

> - d3wordcloud
>
>   - d3wordcloud.info
>   - d3wordcloud.module

*d3wordcloud.info*:

```
name = "D3 Word Cloud"
description = "Provides a block with awesome word cloud generated by D3."
package = custom
core = 7.x
dependencies[] = block
```

*d3wordcloud.module*:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_info().
 *
 * This hook declares what blocks are provided by the module.
 */
function d3wordcloud_block_info() {
  $blocks['word_cloud'] = array(
    // info: The name of the block.
    'info' => t('Display a pretty word cloud generated by D3'),
    'status' => TRUE,
  );
  return $blocks;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_block_view().
 *
 * This hook generates the contents of the blocks
 */
function d3wordcloud_block_view($delta = '') {
  //The $delta parameter tells us which block is being requested.
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'word_cloud':
      $block['subject'] = t("wordcloud");
      $block['content'] = '<div id="d3-wordcloud"></div>';
      break;
  }
  return $block;
}
```

Within the code that generates the block you can use [drupal_add_js](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7) to include both the D3 js and the word cloud js. If you then copy the script you have in your html into a .js file as well you can put a drupal_add_js in for that as well. Wrap everything but the *draw* function as follows

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // code that initialises drawing
});

function draw() {...
```

More drupal javascript
 info [here](https://drupal.org/node/171213)

The actual block content then just has to return a placeholder for your wordcloud, eg `<div id="d3-wordcloud"></div>`. Your script looks like it draws straight into the body tag, so replace `d3.select("body")` with `d3.select("#d3-wordcloud")` so that the cloud ends up in your block.

### Option 2 - bit more drupally and extensible?

- Install the D3 module, which supplies d3 via the libraries api
- Create custom module (using parts of the d3_example module as a template):

  - expose the D3 word cloud project as a library
  - make use of the word cloud in your block

### Option 3 - re-usable module

As option 2 but also create a fork or patch for the [tagcloud](https://drupal.org/project/tagclouds) module which uses your D3 word cloud library in place of its own display. This solution will give you a block for each taxonomy vocabulary tailored to the terms associated with the viewed node.

Comment: Hi autopoietic, I have tried the Option 1. I found some problem. I have taken a screenshot of what I have done and here is the link to the screenshot.
1)
http://egitraining.esc.rl.ac.uk/images/d3%20html.jpg

2) http://egitraining.esc.rl.ac.uk/images/d3%20module.jpg

Please check the highlighted part and let me know where I am wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Hi autopoietic, I am glad that you are back. Can you tell me how do I add JS files, I have tried drupal_add_js and #attached method but unable to add the files. Secondly I can't put the html file content into JS as I have to call the html file which will then call the remaining two JS files. Can you Please help me with this?

Comment: I may have missed something but I am not sure why you would need to import the html in this case - is that not the part drupal is playing for you?

drupal_add_js should work, but if you are having problems, you could try adding it via your theme info file or move the druupal_add_js out of hook_block and into hook_preprocess_page: https://drupal.org/node/304255

Comment: Hi,I added the d3.js and d3.layout.cloud.js using the theme.info and it worked. I used your method which you described in first option. Here is the link to what I did to make it work. http://egitraining.esc.rl.ac.uk/images/4.jpg 
I tried to copy all this in js and put the js using theme.info but it didn't work. I read somewhere that It needs <meta charset = "utf-8">. Please let me know if you think I can add it using any other way. At the moment, I have this problem, Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028492/why-text-goes-out-of-the-box-while-using-d3-word-cloud-example-by-jason-davies

Comment: I am (belatedly) glad you got this working.